# Related Rates Integration

Tags: calculus, integration

A right angled triangle ABC has a fixed hypotenuse AC of length 10. Side AB increases at 0.1 cm/s. At what rate is the angle CAB increasing when the triangle is isosceles.

My try:
Let x = side AB. Therefore dx/dt= 0.1 cm/s
let angle CAB = y

cos(y)=x/10
therefore dy/dt=-1/100sin(y) (radians/second).

Now i need to find the angle y for when the triangle is isosceles i.e. x=10. I have tried many ways but i just cannot find angle y whatsoever. I don't know what to do. Am i missing something obvious?

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

The triangle is isosceles when $AB = x = BC$ so by the Pythagorean Theorem you have
$$
x^2+x^2=10^2 \iff x = \sqrt{50} = 5\sqrt2.
$$

Comment: but when the triangle is iscosceles, you cant use the pythag theorem right. When the triangle is iscosceles, i know what x is, x=10. But i need to find the top angle (y) of this isosceles triangle.